# Memory Error While Closing The Application

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

While closing the application in Delphi 7, I am getting following error:

"The instruction at 0x011c34a6 referenced memory at 0x018333f4. The memory could not be read."

Any idea what is causing this issue ?

Comment: I removed all the tags for delphi versions that you aren't using. Also, no need to sign your name in your post, Stack Overflow automatically includes a sig.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is an Access Violation exception. It is raised when your program attempts to access an invalid memory address.

The most obvious cause is that you are accessing memory that has been deallocated and returned to the system. I recommend that you execute under the debugger and let the debugger break at the code that raises the exception. This will tell you what object you are referencing and then you've got to work out why you are referencing it after the object has been destroyed.

Having said that, the instruction pointer value of 0x011c34a6 doesn't look like it's in your exe which will be based at 0x00400000. So perhaps the exception is raised in a DLL which may make the fault a little more tricky to debug.

I recommend that you use the FastMM memory manager with full debug options rather than the default Borland MM from Delphi 7. FastMM has lots of debugging tools to help locate and diagnose faults such as this. It may help track down this fault, but if not it will for sure help you find other faults in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Vishal. I could be several things.
If you are trying to free or acces something that has been freed ealier in your code, this will happend.
If you step your way through your code that is executed during application shut down, you might catch the error.
Are you using threads?

Comment: I am not using threads. When I am freeing all the objects, there is no error. When FormDestroy event is executed without any error, then I get this error message. While executing my code this error is not coming. This message comes up when delphi has finished the FormDestroy event

Comment: @Vishal: Try and not free the objects to see if you can identify the object causing it. I've sometimes had to do work-arounds to fix these isues...

Comment: @Vishal If you would just, as I suggested, run under the debugger, with Break On Exceptions enabled, then the debugger would help.

Comment: It's in the debugger options.

Comment: Ya, got it... Tools->Debugger Options->Language Exception->Stop on Delphi Exception...

Comment: After distroy event, i strat debugging, it goes to Form.pas (Delphi's own file), there after executing the "DoneApplication" procedure, I get the error: Project <.exe path> raised too many consecutive exceptions, access violation at 0x011f34a6: read of address 0x01806aac. rocess stopped. Then I continuw By F8 then I get CPU window, again I continuw with F8 till I reach to the line  Call ntDll.NtContinue

Comment: Step through DoneApplication. I trust you have Debug DCUs enabled.